# wandb: get a list of all artifact collections and all aliases of those artifacts

Tags: python, wandb

The wandb documentation doesn't seem to explain how to do this - but it should be a fairly common use case I'd imagine?

I achieved mostly (but not completely) what I wanted like this, but it seems a bit clunky? I'd have expected to have an `self.aliases` property on the `ArtifactCollection` instances?

UPDATE: it does seem to be part of the sdk from >= v0.13.10:
https://github.com/wandb/wandb/blob/v0.13.10/wandb/apis/public.py#L4050-L4053

```py
ENTITY = os.environ.get("WANDB_ENTITY")
API_KEY = os.environ.get("WANDB_API_KEY")

def get_model_artifacts(key=None):
    wandb.login(key=key if key is not None else API_KEY)
    api = wandb.Api(overrides={"entity": ENTITY})
    model_names = [
        i
        for i in api.artifact_type(
            type_name="models", project="train"
        ).collections()
    ]
    for model in model_names:
        artifact = api.artifact("train/" + model.name + ":latest")
        model._attrs.update(artifact._attrs)
        model._attrs["metadata"] = json.loads(model._attrs["metadata"])
        model.aliases = [x["alias"] for x in model._attrs["aliases"]]
    return model_names
```

I guess I could possibly look into writing a custom graph-ql query if needed or just use this clunky method.

Am I missing something? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

The one thing this clunky method is missing is any old aliases - it only shows the latest model and then any aliases of that (let's say "latest" and also "v4" etc.) - not sure how this would/should be displayed but I'd have hoped to be able to get old aliases as well (i.e. aliases that point to old versions of the artifact). Although, this is less important.

**EDIT** - after a few hours looking through their sdk code, I have this (still not that happy with how clunky it is):

```py
ENTITY = os.environ.get("WANDB_ENTITY")
API_KEY = os.environ.get("WANDB_API_KEY")

def get_model_artifacts(key=None):
    wandb.login(key=key if key is not None else API_KEY)
    api = wandb.Api(overrides={"entity": ENTITY})
    model_artifacts = [
        a
        for a in api.artifact_type(
            type_name="models", project="train"
        ).collections()
    ]

    def get_alias_tuple(artifact_version):
        version = None
        aliases = []
        for a in artifact_version._attrs["aliases"]:
            if re.match(r"^v\d+$", a["alias"]):
                version = a["alias"]
            else:
                aliases.append(a["alias"])
        return version, aliases

    for model in model_artifacts:
        # artifact = api.artifact("train/" + model.name + ":latest")
        # model._attrs.update(artifact._attrs)
        # model._attrs["metadata"] = json.loads(model._attrs["metadata"])
        versions = model.versions()
        version_dict = dict(get_alias_tuple(version) for version in versions)
        model.version_dict = version_dict
        model.aliases = [
            x for key, val in model.version_dict.items() for x in [key] + val
        ]
    return model_artifacts
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm Annirudh. I'm an engineer at W&B who helped build artifacts. Your solution is really close, but by using the `latest` alias when fetching the artifact we're only going to be considering the aliases from that one artifact instead of all the versions. You could get around that by looping over the versions:

```
api = wandb.Api()
collections = [
    coll for coll in api.artifact_type(type_name=TYPE, project=PROJECT).collections()
]


aliases = set()
for coll in collections:
    for artifact in coll.versions():
        aliases.update(artifact.aliases)

print(collections)
print(aliases)
```

Currently, the documentation is spare on collections but we're polishing them up in the public API and will release some docs around it shortly. These APIs aren't quite release ready yet -- so apologies for the rough edges.

Please feel free to reach out to me directly in the future if you have any other questions regarding artifacts. Always happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Annirudh. So it looks like I was on the right track. Is it correct that each time we run coll.versions() we do another graph-ql http request? So the number of http requests can end up being n + 1, where n is the number of artifact collections? Is it possible to think about just adding the versions info into the artifact_type graph-ql http request so that we just have 1 http request? Or is my thinking off here? (I'm thinking either wandb authors like yourself could update the graph-ql or potentially I could etc.)

Comment: So the `coll.versions()` call will generate 1 HTTP request per 50 versions (the results are paginated). If you want to minimize this, you can pass in `per_page` (`coll.versions(per_page=500)`).

The backend caps the per_page limit to 500, so you can't exceed that.

Would the number of requests be a problem for your use case?

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question. You are concerned that for each collection, we will be issuing a separate `coll.versions()` query. The number of HTTP requests for the above snippet will end up being `O(c + v)` where `c` is the number of collections in the artifact type and `v` is the number of versions in the artifact type. Practically, `v` will be scaled by the `per_page` setting.

Comment: Yeah ideally I'd just love one http request to return a list of ArtifactCollections and on each of those ArtifactCollections I'd like a property such as self.aliases with a list of all the aliases of that ArtifactCollection? Maybe the caveat here would be that the number of versions/aliases would be limited to 50. Is that why this is not included here as potentially it starts to make the graphql request over-fetch for most users?

Comment: We didn't anticipate `aliases` at the collection level being useful, but I'd be happy to add it. I agree that it is useful to know all the `aliases` that are available for a given collection, but I'd be curious about how you would use that information in your use case.

Comment: Our use case is that we tag/alias our models as "latest" and/or "prod" to determine what models are still being evaluated/tested and what models are live in production. For a short period, the "latest" models are not in prod yet and are being tested in a replica environment (user acceptance, end-to-end type testing). Also, we tag/alias our models to essentially categorize them into groups of models and different API endpoints/routes require different group(s) of models. Not sure if there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: What we used to do was have a list of model names and their group(s) and their stage(s) stored in a json file on the server and our inference code would read this and know what group(s) of models to load for each API route. However, we wanted to move to a more nible approach where we load the model names and their group(s) and their stage(s) by using the answer you provided above (thanks again for all your help and engagement on this - do you guys also have a slack channel etc.?)

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense! So for a given model, which might have several versions, you want to check the total list of aliases to see if it has `latest` or `prod` to determine which are live in production. I'd be happy to add this at the "collection" level to make this easier. 

We were thinking that for a given model, users would care more about which specific version is tagged with an alias like `prod` rather than the whole artifact.

Yes, please join our Slack (wb-forum.slack.com)! Feel free to DM me there, I'm @annirudh.

Comment: Yeah exactly (the other thing I considered is just a try-catch around loading models like "entity/project/model_name::prod" etc. to find out if there is a prod version of the model ready etc. but that's less elegant).  And "tagging" models into different groups using aliases is also really useful for us. Thanks a lot appreciate it. I guess that might be your internal Slack? I tried to join but it said I needed a wandb email. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJPDf.png no worries. Maybe I can use this https://community.wandb.ai/ -  it's a bit like a Slack clone it seems.

Comment: Looks like we transitioned our community from Slack to our new portal at https://community.wandb.ai/ -- apologies for the outdated information in the comment above.

Some good news: we'll be adding `aliases` as a property at the collection level in the next CLI release. The alias grouping will be done in the backend, so we'll only need to make a single HTTP request for them.

Comment: That's awesome thanks a lot for the update. I'll keep an eye out for the next CLI release. Do CLI releases automatically propagate into the python sdk library?

Comment: Ahh nevermind the CLI is the python library (https://github.com/wandb/client/blob/master/setup.py#L48-L53) - I hadn't really used the CLI up until now to be honest.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, we use the terms CLI and Python SDK interchangeably because they are both in the same codebase. Yes, this update will propagate into the SDK.

Comment: Do you know which version this will be in Annirudh? Or just roughly when etc.? (I took at look at the releases in the last 3 weeks ish but I didn't see anything mentioning it - although I guess it could be hidden or not so promenant etc. https://github.com/wandb/client/releases)